# Rellenar un JTextfield de un formulario abierto desde otro JFrame abierto - JAVA SWING

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, jdialog

tengo un jframe con jtextfield, si al lado tengo un boton buscar y se me abre un jdialog, de forma que me deje buscar entre los posibles valores, como puedo hacer, de forma que si selecciono un valor, al cerrar ese jdialog,me apareza en el jtextfield el valor seleccionado desde el jdialog.
Mediante el constructor no puedo porque el jframe está ya iniciado

gracias

Comment: Hola, podrias decirnos lo que intentastes?

Comment: Tengo una aplicación de reparto, y cada jornada de trabajo se asigna a un repartidor ruta  y vehículo. Hay un jframe donde a un repartidor se asgina ruta y vehículo. Hay un campo JTexfield donde se introduce la matrícula y al lado un boton pequeño [+], que al darle se abre un Jdialog con modal=true, donde puedes buscar los vehículos no asignados para asignar, cuando seleccionas el vehículo se cierra ese Jdialog y la matricula del vehículo seleccionado aparece en el JFrame. Al abrir el JDialog, el JFrame no se cierra. Lo que no se es como devolver el valor del JDialog al JFrame